# Do we have export test cases functionality in Testrigor automation tool?

Tags: testrigor

we need to know more on how to export test results once all test cases are passed.

Can anyone clarify whether export test cases option available in testrigor tool.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Can we get export functionality( excel,PDF) within testrigor in upcoming releases?

Answer (score 0):

From testRigor support:

> testRigor doesn't currently have a way to export reports in an excel file or similar. They only send reports to email, slack or Teams currently. If you want to export something from your platform of choice, it should be possible, but, not from testRigor.

That's a nice way to say that you have to print the email.  :-)